# four buttons with rounded corners and different colors

Tags: android, xml, button

Ive seen a few things on here about rounded corners and colored backgrounds but nothing that quite suits my needs.

The way that I have seen to make a rounded corner button (which works) is to create a xml file in the drawable folder, then put something like such.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="@color/Blue"/>
  <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>  
</shape>
```

and thats great, for one button. is there a way I can combined four colors into one xml file so i dont have to make four separate ones? I want them all to have 10dp radius like this blue button, but each have their own respective colors.

what im asking is the only way that i can get the rounded edges is to say in my main xml file is `android:background="@drawable/round` which would be fine if i could say that and then `android:background="@color/Blue"` but since i cant make to calls to `android:background` I had to name the color in this drawable xml file. SO now i dont know how to change the color dynamically in this round.xml file
regards.

Comment: you want to make 4 buttons, each of different color in single file

Comment: for changing color of drawable at run time.....I think you should create this drawable programmatically in .java file ...and change the color whenever required

Comment: there are four constant buttons, each their own color. the color of each doesnt ever change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define one xml and change button colors dynamically by following:

```
    GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) button1.getBackground();
    sd.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            GradientDrawable sd1 = (GradientDrawable) button2.getBackground();
    sd1.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: would i do that in the onCreate? im pretty new so im just looking for a straight answer that wont confuse me too bad :)

Comment: yes in onCreate. just after you call findViewById for a button call this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current background of the button as a drawable and then set a tint to change its color with the below code:

```
Drawable drawable = button1.getBackground();
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.BLACK);
```